# Mutual authentication vs. trusted third-party authentication

Tags: security, authentication, cryptography, protocols

What are the similarity and differences?  I know they both authenticate both party's identity, but when to use which?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography, try crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that they aren't the same, and they aren't alternatives either. Mutual authentication simply means that both peers authenticate each other, e.g. in SSL with client authentication. Third-party trusted authentication is an authentication *mechanism,* which could be used in mutual authentication. X.509 certificates as used in SSL are an example.